# Why rotation matrix of SO(3) can have more than 3 dimensions?

Tags: group-theory

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876529/how-can-a-representation-of-so3-be-more-than-3-dimensional), but I still don't get it. [The definition of SO(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) says it's defined on three-dimensional Euclidean space, but I know that there are [matrices of SO(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) can be applied to higher dimension space.

Is it because the high-dimensional space can be transformed to three-dimensional Euclidean space?

EDIT: The answer of that [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876529/how-can-a-representation-of-so3-be-more-than-3-dimensional) says SO(3) is not necessarily related to the dimensions of vector space. But I think there must be some relationship between the high-dimensional matrices and three-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Think of $SO(3)$ as acting on polynomials in three variables, $x,y,z$, by linear substitutions. When that action is restricted to homogeneous *linear* polynomials you get a 3-dimensional representation of $SO(3)$ because the space of such polynomials is spanned by $x,y$ and $z$. However, when you look at the same action on the space of homogeneous quadratic polynomials, the dimension goes up, because those are spanned by the six monomials $x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz$.

Comment: (cont'd) This gives a group homomorphism from $SO(3)$ to $GL(6)$. In other words, a way of replacing each matrix in $SO(3)$ with a $6\times 6$ matrix in such a way that a product of any two matrices in $SO(3)$ gets mapped to the product of the corresponding $6\times6$ matrices.

Comment: (cont'd) Observe that because any orthogonal transformation preserves lengths, the quadratic form $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is mapped to itself by any matrix $g\in SO(3)$. This implies that the 6-dimensional representation of $SO(3)$ on homogeneous quadratic polynomials has 1-dimensional trivial subrepresentation. Anyway, you really need to pick up a book on representation theory.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much for your comment! I think I got it now. Also the simple direct sum can give more high dimensional matrix representations.